# Second thread enters lock before first thread releases it

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task-parallel-library

I'm playing with some threading constructs in C#, and ran into something that defies my understanding of how locking works. I have a helper function that accepts an asynchronous task, and uses a `TaskCompletionSource` member to try and synchronize access when called multiple times.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new TestClass();
    var task1 = test.Execute("First Task", async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
    var task2 = test.Execute("Second Task", async () => await Task.Delay(1000));

    task1.Wait();
    task2.Wait();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _activeTaskCompletionSource;

    public async Task Execute(string source, Func<Task> actionToExecute)
    {
        Task activeTask = null;
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            if (_activeTaskCompletionSource != null)
            {
                activeTask = _activeTaskCompletionSource.Task;
            }
            else
            {
                _activeTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            }
        }

        while (activeTask != null)
        {
            await activeTask;
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                if (_activeTaskCompletionSource != null)
                {
                    activeTask = _activeTaskCompletionSource.Task;
                }
                else
                {
                    activeTask = null;
                }
            }
        }

        await actionToExecute();
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            _activeTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
            _activeTaskCompletionSource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This always ends up falling into an infinite loop for the second task. I put some code to log each step as it happens, and it always produces something like this (I've manually inserted comments after #s):

```
[First Task] Waiting for lock (setup)
[First Task] Entered lock (setup)
[First Task] Grabbing '_activeTaskCompletionSource' (setup)
[First Task] Lock released (setup)
[First Task] RUNNING ...
[Second Task] Waiting for lock (setup)
[Second Task] Entered lock (setup)
[Second Task] Assigning 'activeTask' (setup)
[Second Task] Lock released (setup)
[Second Task] Waiting for task to complete ...
[First Task] COMPLETED!
[First Task] Waiting for lock (cleanup)
[First Task] Entered lock (cleanup)
[First Task] Setting _activeTaskCompletionSource result ...
    # Never gets to '_activeTaskCompletionSource = null'
    # Never gets to 'Releasing lock (cleanup)' for first task
[Second Task] Awaited task completed!
[Second Task] Waiting for lock (loop)
    # Immediately enters lock after 'await' is complete
    # Does not wait for 'First Task' to finish its lock!
[Second Task] Entered lock (loop)
[Second Task] Assigning 'activeTask' (loop)
[Second Task] Lock released (loop)
[Second Task] Waiting for task to complete ...
[Second Task] Awaited task completed!
```

This ultimately sends the second task into an infinite loop, because `_activeTaskCompletionSource` is never set back to `null`.

I was under the impression that **no other thread** could ever enter a lock until all previous threads had exited it, but here, my `First Task` thread never finishes and releases its cleanup lock before the `Second Task` thread grabs hold of it.

Does this have anything to do with mixing locks and async/await?

Comment: It is definately not recommended to make a task.Wait() or task.Result to an async task, since it could easily end up in a deadlock case.

Comment: @OsmanEsen The `task.Wait()` calls in this example are only used because it's running in a console application, where it is _impossible_ to use async/await in the main function. I've avoided using blocking calls in all of the async functions themselves, and all throughout the `TestClass` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` can inline continuations causing unexpected and arbitrary code to run under the lock. `await` uses continuations, too.

This nasty behavior is a design bug in the TPL. If you care about this [there is a GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2454). Leave a comment there.

Comment: Specifically if you are on .NET 4.6 you can work around it by changing your creation of the completion source to `_activeTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);`

Comment: Ouch! That's painful. I assumed it was something I had done wrong, not something bugged in the framework itself. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

As [boot4Life points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295209/80274), this is a design bug with the framework that allows continuations from `SetResult` to run on the same thread.

To work around it if you are on .NET 4.6 change your creation of the completion source to

```
_activeTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
```

This stops it from happening. If you are only on 4.5.x you must run the completion on a new thread to prevent it from being picked up.

```
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
        var completionSource = _activeTaskCompletionSource;
        _activeTaskCompletionSource = null;
        Task.Run(() => completionSource.SetResult(true));            
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck on 4.5, so it looks like your workaround for running it on its own thread is going to be required.

Answer (score 1):

Try SemaphorSlim. The lock statement is not the right tool for the job with the task based async scenario.

Also, there is a temptation to await tasks that are already going on in a class externally, but my understanding is that if you do that, they will not be awaited unless you use ConfigureAwait correctly. Semaphore slim solves this problem because as far as I know, it will await the lock no matter what.

```
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _RefreshLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    public virtual async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _RefreshLock.WaitAsync();

            //Your work here

        }
        finally
        {
            _RefreshLock.Release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware this existed. I'll have to check it out for future async/await stuff.